# How to update dictionary value in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

How to 
*get* and
*update*
the  specific element from the array in the dictionary?

```
var currency : [String: [Double]]  = [
    "EUR": [1,1],
    "USD": [1.06,1.05],
    "CHF": [1.07, 1.06]
]
```

I'm working on currency converter and I need to get eg. the second value (buy rate, in this case: "1.05") to make calculations.

Comment: That's a good example to use a custom struct. It makes things so much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let eur_exchangeRate = currency["EUR"]
```

This will give you the corresponding array of doubles from the dictionary.

```
let buyRate = eur_exchangeRate![1]
```

This will give you the second element in the array of doubles (which, I believe is the buy rate you're wanting to access)

```
currency["EUR"]![1] = 99
```

This will set your buy rate for EUROS to 99.

Please look at @vadian's comment on your question to get an idea of a cleaner implementation of these sort.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to ever advocate using forced unwrapping (`!`), even in examples where we know the key to exist (it might reinforce the misconception that using `!` for runtime-decided entities is actually "safe"). There are safer ways to perform both the wrapping and inner array access above.

Answer (score 0):

My tested solution in swift 4.2 for dictionary like [String : [String]]

```
   yourDict![existingKey]![positionOfValueToUpdate] = newValue
```

example:

```
var myDict = [keyOne : ["valueA","valueB","valueC","valueD"]

let newValue = "valueX"

myDict![keyOne]![2] = newValue
```

after this myDict will be:

```
myDict = [keyOne : ["valueA","valueB","valueX","valueD"]
```